# My late 2009 MacBook 6,1 windows 10 is corrupted

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows, install, data-transfer

I have a late 2009 MacBook 6,1 just for gaming purposes. I tried rolling back my system using system restore but unfortunately, my machine went off in the middle of the process. I got error code: critical process died and I think my windows 10 is corrupted. Currently I can't also access the macos partition(I don't know why. seems it just disappeared). Is there a way to freshly install or download windows 10 again when you can't get into macos ? Please help.

Comment: Are you saying you can not boot to Windows, macOS or macOS Recovery? Do you have any other computers that you can use to download software?

Comment: There is a Mid 2009 MacBook5,2 and Late 2009 MacBook6,1, but there is no Mid 2009 MacBook6,1. Knowing which would help. What color is the MacBook? Do you know which version of OS X/macOS was installed? Do you know if Windows 10 was 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: When I turn the PC on, it loads as usual then the blue screen comes up and gives the code : "critical process died" always. I then went to the troubleshooting interface and tried reinstalling windows via cloud or local download but it couldn't. I then restarted it and held the ALT key so it shows me the two OSs(windows partition and macos) to select from but I only have the windows. I can't find the macos.

Comment: It's late 2009 MacBook 6,1. sorry. OS : Pre-installed OS: 10.6.1. Upgraded to OS10.10.4. Windows 10 was 64bit

Comment: I can get to the windows recovery just fine. But I can't boot into macos, it's only windows I see to choose from. My main concern is, can I download or install windows again without having to boot into macos. Like downloading windows on the PC using USB drive... without having anything to do with getting into macos on the same PC which I can't access the macos ?

Comment: You can use a PC running Windows to [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) the media create tool, then use the tool to create the USB installer. This will not be the same as if you downloaded the ISO from macOS. You should **NOT** be able to boot the USB installer on your MacBook, but you can try if you are so incline. For drivers, you should use the "Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4.033" which can be found [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016). I realize the download is for Windows 7, but Apple did not release Windows 10 driver for you model.

Comment: Booting and installing is going to be tricky. You best bet is to burn a DVD if you can not boot from the USB installer. You might be able to install by booting to Windows Recovery.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to get into recovery by using the power button to restart your computer three times or something but do not actually have recovery media I'm afraid you're going to need to download windows on a working PC, make a USB and use that.  You could ask a friend.

Comment: After creating a bootable USB drive from a different PC, I just need to insert it to my MacBook then access the startup disk and choose the USB drive and proceed from there please ?

Comment: I can get to windows recovery but not macos recovery